# When using the useFactory method of '@nestjs/jwt', how do I re-fetch the signing keys if a kid is not in the current array of keys?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs

I'm quite new to nestJS and this whole backend business so please be gentile. I'm trying to set up authentication through a JWKS client. My current setup works.. for a while. On deployment it fetches the current public keys but after a while my auth provider (Zitadel) rotates in new keys and the app doesn't fetch the new ones.

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
      async useFactory() {
        const jwksUri = process.env.KEYS_URL;

        const client = new JwksClient({
          cache: true,
          rateLimit: true,
          jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
          jwksUri: jwksUri,
        });

        const keys = await client.getSigningKeys()
        return {
          secretOrKeyProvider(requestType, token: string) {
            const decoded = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });

            const key: JwksRsa.SigningKey = keys.find((key) => key.kid === decoded.header.kid);

            const publicKey = key.getPublicKey();
            return publicKey;
          },
          verifyOptions: {
            algorithms: ['RS256'],
          },
        };
      },
      global: true,
    }),
```

The first `const keys = await client.getSigningKeys()` comes through, but I can't put async code in the `secretOrKeyProvider` method. How do I refetch key if the kid on the `token` isn't present in the `keys` array?